# NSToolbar icons remain solid black instead of receiving the nice gray system effect

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

The *[Designing Toolbar Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABIFCFJ)*' section of [OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TP6) says that the system applies effects on icons in the toolbar that change their appearance. In other words, we have to create a *solid black* icon like this:

[image: Solid black icon]

and the system displays it like this:

[image: System processed icon]

That's great, but it does not work for me.

I'm using Interface Builder. I have a Rounded Textured Button inside a NSToolbarItem:

[image: Interface Builder Hierarchy]

I have assigned a solid black icon to the toolbar item:

[image]

When I show it, however, it appears like a... solid black icon:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? This thing is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to rename your icon from `Test` to `TestTemplate`. You can find more information about this trick in [OS X Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#TextAndImageEffects).

Comment: WOW. I can't believe this is all it took. I was pulling my hair out for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with an NSImage object directly (not in Interface Builder) you can call [myImage setTemplate:YES] and it will exhibit the special drawing behavior.